# preg expression to match four consecutive consonants excluding "chr" group

Tags: php, regex

```
$string = "sqrtpdrt"; // matched
$string = "qwntfschrprtkjs"; // not matched (contains chr group)
```

I use

```
preg_match('/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]{4}/i', $string )
```

to match 4 consecutive consonants, but now I what to exclude strings containing "chr" group.

Comment: `chr` will be together or can they appear separately in the input?

Comment: Ok good then below answer should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not the best pattern of the world, but it must do the job:

```
preg_match('~(?!.*chr)^.*[bcdfghj-np-tvwxz]{4}~si', $string);
```

pattern details:

```
~                     # pattern delimiter
(?!.*chr)             # negative lookahead: not followed by something and "chr"
^                     # start of the string anchor
.*                    # anything zero or more times
[bcdfghj-np-tvwxz]{4} # (it's shorter with ranges!)
~si                   # the s modifier allows the dot to match newlines
```

you can also do the opposite:

```
preg_match('~(?=.*[bcdfghj-np-tvwxz]{4})^(?>[^c]++|c(?!hr))+$~is', $string);
```

pattern details:

```
~
(?=.*[bcdfghj-np-tvwxz]{4}) # lookahead: followed by something and 4 consonants
^
(?>                         # open an atomic group
    [^c]++                  # all that is not a "c"
  |                         # OR
    c(?!hr)                 # "c" not followed by "hr" (negative lookahead)
)+                          # repeat the group one or more times (possessive)
$                           # end of the string anchor
~is
```